# How to find Snmp Packet size of the request and response using adventnet/webnms SnmpTarget alone

Tags: java, snmp, webnms

I have tried to get the size of Snmp packet sent during the request and received during the response. I'm trying to find those packets' sizes. I have to use only the adventnet/webnms's SnmpTarget class to find the same. But I have found no method to get the packet size. Is there anyother way to get those packet sizes using advenetnet/webnms's SnmpTarget?
(The language I'm using is Java)

Comment: What do you mean by packet size, the network packet size, the payload?

Comment: @LuisMuñoz By Packet size, I mean the size of the request and response messages in bytes.